# If I do not allow the Source button in CKEditor Will my Application be secure

Tags: php, security, ckeditor, bbcode

I am using the CKEditor to let the users post their comments. I am not using the bbcode in my forum. If I hide the source button of CKEditor and do the following steps

1. use htmlspecialchars() function to handle the html elements
2. user parse_url to ensure that the data has been submitted from my own domain

Am I securely handling the user submitted data? Do I still need to use bbcode? What more steps should I take to make my application more secure.

Comment: Showing no source button on client side gives you no security. Using parse_url gives you no security either. `htmlspecialchars` does give you security but note that if you allow the user to use any html (like `<b>`), `htmlspecialchars` will make bold text plaintext with `<b>` and `</b>` surroundings.

Comment: Are users permitted to use HTML tags? If so, you'll need to filter what tags and attributes are permitted.

Answer (score 2):

You won't secure your code by hidding that button. In fact, nothing you do on the client side will help.

I strongly suggest you to check what your users post before adding it to your DB. 
Last time I had to deal with such thing, I used a combination of [PHPIDS](https://phpids.org/) and [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) but that was long ago and I don't know if they're the best tools for that nowadays.